# How to send latest extent reports through mail without using Jenkins, I am always getting the previous mail instead of latest generated mail?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports

I have tried sending reports through mail extent report and emailable report but it's always sending the previous report. I have to send mail through my local system.

Comment: when u r sending mail now? you have to trigger once execution is completed and report are ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SMTP protocol, to send mail from Local System . You can use Google SMTP IP and Port.
The SMTP password is the same as your web password, unless you are using 2SV.
Use smtp.gmail.com, port 465, SSL or port 587/STARTTLS.

Comment: I have already used it but no luck. When should I call send mail function so that mail will be sent after all test execution.